# how to access object values in lightning aura component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, community

I want to render a table dynamically in lightning. I have a list of data of transaction (Custom object) and  list of string which contains API name which data i want to render.

I have created a child component and wrapped it in nested aura iteration to display the data. But I am unable to access the value.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.Transactions}" var="trans">
       <tr>
       <aura:iteration items="{!v.fieldNames}" var="field" indexVar="ind">
         <td><c:TransactionOutputField object="{!trans}" fieldName="{!field}"/></td>
       </aura:iteration>
       </tr>
</aura:iteration>
```

### child component

```
<aura:component>
  <aura:attribute name="object" type="Object" />
  <aura:attribute name="fieldName" type="String" />
  <aura:attribute name="fieldVal" type="String" access="private" />
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.myAction}"/>

  {!v.fieldVal}
</aura:component>
```

### controller

```
({
    myAction : function(component, event, helper) {

        var sobject = component.get("{!v.object}");
        var fieldName  = component.get("{!v.fieldName}");


        console.log(JSON.stringify(sobject));
        console.log(fieldName);

        var value = sobject[fieldName];
        component.set("v.fieldVal", value);

        console.log(value);


    }
})
```

### debug value in browser

```
{"Id":"a0l1q000000BYLPAA4","Name":"0002000331","akritiv__Amount__c":400,"akritiv__Balance__c":400,"akritiv__Days_Past_Due__c":358,"akritiv__Source_System__c":"SAPG","akritiv__Batch_Number__c":"20181003124027"}
components/c/TransactionOutputField.js:17 Name
components/c/TransactionOutputField.js:22 0002000331
components/c/TransactionOutputField.js:16 {"Id":"a0l1q000000BYLPAA4","Name":"0002000331","akritiv__Amount__c":400,"akritiv__Balance__c":400,"akritiv__Days_Past_Due__c":358,"akritiv__Source_System__c":"SAPG","akritiv__Batch_Number__c":"20181003124027"}
components/c/TransactionOutputField.js:17 akritiv__balance__c
components/c/TransactionOutputField.js:22 undefined
components/c/TransactionOutputField.js:16 {"Id":"a0l1q000000BYLPAA4","Name":"0002000331","akritiv__Amount__c":400,"akritiv__Balance__c":400,"akritiv__Days_Past_Due__c":358,"akritiv__Source_System__c":"SAPG","akritiv__Batch_Number__c":"20181003124027"}
components/c/TransactionOutputField.js:17 akritiv__source_system__c
components/c/TransactionOutputField.js:22 undefined
components/c/TransactionOutputField.js:16 {"Id":"a0l1q000000BYLPAA4","Name":"0002000331","akritiv__Amount__c":400,"akritiv__Balance__c":400,"akritiv__Days_Past_Due__c":358,"akritiv__Source_System__c":"SAPG","akritiv__Batch_Number__c":"20181003124027"}
components/c/TransactionOutputField.js:17 akritiv__batch_number__c
components/c/TransactionOutputField.js:22 undefined
components/c/TransactionOutputField.js:16 {"Id":"a0l1q000000BYLPAA4","Name":"0002000331","akritiv__Amount__c":400,"akritiv__Balance__c":400,"akritiv__Days_Past_Due__c":358,"akritiv__Source_System__c":"SAPG","akritiv__Batch_Number__c":"20181003124027"}
components/c/TransactionOutputField.js:17 akritiv__Notes__c
components/c/TransactionOutputField.js:22 undefined
components/c/TransactionOutputField.js:16 {"Id":"a0l1q000000BYLQAA4","Name":"0002000332","akritiv__Amount__c":0,"akritiv__Balance__c":0,"akritiv__Source_System__c":"SAPG","akritiv__Batch_Number__c":"20181003124027"}
components/c/TransactionOutputField.js:17 Name
components/c/TransactionOutputField.js:22 0002000332
components/c/TransactionOutputField.js:16 {"Id":"a0l1q000000BYLQAA4","Name":"0002000332","akritiv__Amount__c":0,"akritiv__Balance__c":0,"akritiv__Source_System__c":"SAPG","akritiv__Batch_Number__c":"20181003124027"}
components/c/TransactionOutputField.js:17 akritiv__balance__c
components/c/TransactionOutputField.js:22 undefined
components/c/TransactionOutputField.js:16 {"Id":"a0l1q000000BYLQAA4","Name":"0002000332","akritiv__Amount__c":0,"akritiv__Balance__c":0,"akritiv__Source_System__c":"SAPG","akritiv__Batch_Number__c":"20181003124027"}
components/c/TransactionOutputField.js:17 akritiv__source_system__c
components/c/TransactionOutputField.js:22 undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in right direction. You need to do `sobject[fieldName]` instead of  `obj.field`.

```
var sobject = component.get('v.objName'); //There is also some syntax error so you need to fix them as well
var fieldName = component.get('v.fieldName');
var formatText = component.find("fielddata");
if(!fieldName.includes('.')) {
    formatText.set("v.value",sobject[fieldName]); //sobject[fieldName] this is the key here to get the data
}
```

Child component

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="objName" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="fieldName" type="String" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

    <lightning:formattedText aura:id="fielddata" />
</aura:component>
```

You can check complete code [here](https://newstechnologystuff.com/2018/05/28/display-generic-sobject-in-lightning/)

Comment: Hey @tushar , I am getting data only for Name field and undefined for all the other. Can you please help me ?

Comment: {"Id":"a0l1q000000BYLLAA4","Name":"0002000327","akritiv__Amount__c":0,"akritiv__Balance__c":0,"akritiv__Source_System__c":"SAPG","akritiv__Batch_Number__c":"20181003124027"}
 Name
0002000327
{"Id":"a0l1q000000BYLLAA4","Name":"0002000327","akritiv__Amount__c":0,"akritiv__Balance__c":0,"akritiv__Source_System__c":"SAPG","akritiv__Batch_Number__c":"20181003124027"}
 akritiv__balance__c
undefined

Comment: @Cooolranjan you should check if you are using correct syntax. Share your updated code.

Comment: Hi @tushar-sharma , I shared the updated code and the debug value I am getting in the browser.

Comment: @Cooolranjan instead of this `component.get("{!v.object}");` do this `component.get('v.object');` same for field as well and then share the error if you face any.

Comment: Hey @tushar ,I am not getting any error but it is giving the same output which i posted above. Only Name value is populating and for others It is Undefined.

Comment: @Cooolranjan As Lightning is case sensitive so are you sure your API name is all small caps? if not you need to fix them.

Comment: I believe this is the error . Anyhow i will get back to you after dealing with this . Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Your controller JS is of the wrong syntax. We dont use `{!}` to access data attribute vale in Javascript. We just use 'v.attributeName'. Also your syntax to access map values is wrong. We use MapObject[keyName] to access maps.

```
({
    myAction : function(component, event, helper) {

        var obj = component.get("v.object");
        var field = component.get("v.fieldName");

        console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
        console.log(field);

        var value = obj[field];
        console.log(value);

        component.set("v.fieldVal", value);

    }
})
```

Src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map